# What is the difference between - and -- in python, linux and in windows cmd?

Tags: python, linux, windows, cmd

What is the difference between `-` and `--` in Python and in Linux, I know about operators but in cmd line we will use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` so that's the doubt.

hope some can clear my doubt as soon as possible.
thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Short version: one hyphen is for short form arguments (one letter), two hyphens are for long form arguments (longer than one character). But not every command sticks to this rule.

Comment: @KlausD. Notably, `gcc` and `clang` compilers use one hyphen for everything, as well as QEMU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a programming language. Linux is an operating system kernel.

My guess is that by "in Linux" you mean using a command shell like `bash`. Yes, the language that `bash` processes might reasonably be called a "language." The command shell in Microsoft Windows is `cmd`.

If `bash` is what you mean, then Python and bash are two different languages; in the same way that Python, bash, Java, PHP, C++, and others are all different languages. Each may have its own meaning for the use of `-` and `--`.

It is always important to read the documentation. It is common practice at this time for executable programs to have command line options using `-` for single letter options and `--` for long name options. When using `bash`, see the output of `ls --help` to see the short (single letter) and long options. `-a` and `--all` are equivalent.

Most programs from Microsoft to be run in the `cmd` shell, and those designed for it, typically use `/` to specify options. See `DIR /?` for a list of options that can be used with the `DIR` command.

PowerShell uses `-` like `bash` to indicate options. However, the options can be long names. In a PowerShell console, use the command `help Get-ChildItem -ShowWindow` to see the options (called parameters) that can be used with the `Get-ChildItem` command.

When in doubt, read the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--` instead of `-` are just conventions used in naming/invoking options on the command line, the single dash (-) is usually used on short options, the double dash (--) is used on long options. Many commands will accept either form but you must check the man page and/or manual first.

In your example 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' means:

1. `python -m pip` means to run a module, in this case `pip`
2. `install --upgrade pip` means you are telling `pip` to install an update for the package called `pip`, which will bring it to the latest version available.

If you are on Linux, you can see a summary of options for most commands by typing `-h` or `--help` after the command, for example `python -h`.

`--` is not a valid operator in Python, but `-` is.

I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: `--` are actually two valid operators in Python: minus and negation (`a--b` is `a-(-b)`) or two negations.

Comment: Your right, but then its just two `-` operators acting independently, rather than there being a particular operator that consists of `--` (which, as far as I am aware, doesn't exist).